DeLonghi Magnifica Xs (ecam22110sb) brewing too long/overflowing the cup
After reading the post at DeLonghi Magnifica ESAM3500 brews for too long I have replaced the flowmeter and the flow regulator. Unfortunately this didn't seem to help. One strange this I noticed is that the left side controls seems to be working just fine. The left side controls are the ones for espresso coffee and when you press 1 cup or 2 cups of espresso you actually get exactly what you would expect. Here is the link to the machine https://www.delonghi.com/en-us/s/ECAM22110SB. It's when you use the right side for the "long coffee" you get into a problem. The "2 cups" of long coffee will give you double the water amount it used to give. Any suggestions?

Just checking: Did you try to set the coffee volume? It should be programmable to your preferences.

I don't believe this machine has a water volume setting.

Page 11 in the manual you linked to? It may be at least worth a try.

Thank you for your help, this solved the problem.
